# How to get the name from content-disposition in MIME::Entity part?

Tags: perl, mime

```
my $Parser = new MIME::Parser;
my $entity = $Parser->parse_data( $body );
my @parts = $entity->parts;
for $part(@parts){   
    my $type=$part->mime_type;
    my $bhandle=$part->bodyhandle;

    $header = $part->head();
    $content_disp = $header->get('Content-Disposition');

     if ($type =~ /text/i){
         $bodydata = "";
         if (my $io = $part->open("r")) {
             while (defined($_ = $io->getline)) {
                 $bodydata .= $_;
             }
            $io->close;
            print $bodydata;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [recommended_filename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aHead#recommended_filename) method:

```
$header = $part->head();
$filename = $header->recommended_filename;
```

Be sure to check the return value for sanity.  Note that it can also be `undef`.